# In Windows 11 - any way to quickly have all open windows fit to a screen?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have a big monitor (40"). I usually have many different applications and multiple windows of the same application open (e.g. Chrome). Is there any quick way either 1) within Windows; or 2) using a utility to quickly have all my windows fit to my screen in a visible way?

Note: I realize that with WindowsKey + Tab, I can see all the open windows in a thumbnail view. That's not what I'm talking about. I'm talking about something like the "auto arrange" icons on the desktop feature... but with actual open windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could right-click the taskbar and select "Show windows side by side".
Note that this will resize your windows so they fit within a virtual "grid"
that will be generated by the number of windows.

Only non-minimized windows are moved.

This can be undone by a second right-click on the taskbar and selecting
"Undo Show all windows side by side".

Comment: +1 although a side-note should be added that it may work weird if there are windows that are not resizable. It may overlap another window.